# Correct procedure for inadvertant privacy breach?

Tags: discussion

What's the correct procedure if accidentally one posts private information such as a password?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two ways of handling this...

1) As of 2016, Moderators have the power to [redact content from a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/274274/160519).

2) Moderators can go to the Teachers Lounge chat room and ask the SE team to purge the privacy issue from the edit history of the question.  Up until 2016, this was the only option mods had.

Comment: I was looking for this option, but couldn't find any way to purge edit histories. Any pointers, @MikePennington?

Comment: I always went to the teacher's lounge and asked for an SE mod to do it... usually someone makes it a priority (i.e. within 30 minutes) when you point out that a password was in the edit history.

Comment: Thanks, I assumed that you had an option in the moderator menu for this.

Comment: @TeunVink, take a look at the update I made this morning... it turns out, mods can redact information from a post without help from SE employees

Comment: Thanks For the update Mike!